# WebApplicationFactory passing exception on linux while getting HttpStatusCode 500 on windows

Tags: c#

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with my C# unit tests using NUnit and HttpClient. I have a setup where I'm sending HTTP requests using HttpClient and handling any potential exceptions with EnsureSuccessStatusCode(). However, I'm observing different behaviors between Windows development machines and Linux-based CI/CD environments.

On windows dev machines the test is green cause `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` fails with error 500, caused by a NullReferenceException in the controller.
On the linux based CI/Cd the tests is failing, cause the thrown and cought exception is NullReferenceException not `HttpRequestException` cause the client passes the exception up to the test.

Windows 10 (and 11) uses Visual Studio 2022 and the behavior is ident between VS TestRunner, ReSharper TestRunner and git bash with `dotnet test`. On linux(`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0`) `dotnet test´ is used.

[Setting `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19217) is not an option since the behavior with passed exception via the client is way more helpful. (However windows acts as if it was set)

**My Question is how is this behavior actually configured? Why is it different depending on the os?**

```cs
[OneTimeSetUp]
public async Task OneTimeSetup()
{
    // Configuration setup
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json");

    // Web application setup
    _application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            config.AddConfiguration(configurationBuilder.Build());
        });
    });

    _tokenOptions = _application.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApiTokenOptions>>().Value;

    _client = _application.CreateClient();
}

[Test]
[TestCase(2501)]
[TestCase(0)]
public async Task CreateInvalidMessageTest(int Length)
{
    var userId1 = UUID.Generate();
    // ...

    // Issue lies here: On Windows, EnsureSuccessStatusCode fails with error 500 due to NullReferenceException,
    // whereas on Linux-based CI/CD, the exception thrown and caught is NullReferenceException, not HttpRequestException.
    Assert.ThrowsAsync<HttpRequestException>(async () => await AuthorizedPostRequest($"api/Chatroom/{roomId}", userId1, JsonSerializer.Serialize(body)));
}

protected async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AuthorizedPostRequest(string path, UUID userId, string body, bool failOnNon200 = true)
{
    return await AuthorizedRequest(HttpMethod.Post, path, userId, body, failOnNon200);
}
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AuthorizedRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod/* = HttpMethod.Get*/, string path, UUID userId, string? body = null, bool failOnNon200 = true)
{
    var response = await _client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = httpMethod,
        RequestUri = new Uri(_client.BaseAddress + path),
        Headers = { { "Authorization", "Bearer " + CreateJwt(userId.ToString()) } },
        Content = body != null ? new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") : null,
    });
    if (failOnNon200)
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return response;
}
```